# Why concatenating these layers, why applying masks over and over to partial convoluted image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

I'd like to ask some questions about a topic. In a sentence of [Nvidia's article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.07723) they are saying:

> "The last partial convolution layer’s input will contain the
> concatenation of the original input image with hole and original mask,
> making it possible for the model to copy non-hole pixels."

Why is it important to copy non-hole pixels? What is the purpose? And where is the "concatenation" that mentioned in above sentence in [this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOxwl.png)? (Show with drawing please).

- And why are we concatenating other layers? For at [this structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOxwl.png), why are we concatenating 2 masks and 2 layers? I understand for localization and feature loses etc., but what does it have to do with removing masks and filling the masked places with pixels?
- Why are we adding a new reduced mask to improved features? If you look at [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBqC8.png), they are applying a mask for every partial convolutional layer, and updating the mask. I mean if we want to decrease the mask, why are we applying an updated mask to the partial convolutional image? Wouldn't it just ruin the image?
- What does [this sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz2QQ.png) mean? I tried so hard to understand it, but I could not.